# How do I impose unique style properties on every third element in a column?

Tags: php, html, css

I am new to this site but I need help. I have successfully displayed records from and database with php. The records displays nicely with a CSS class. But what I really want is to change the class name after every three record display. In other words, three records will be display with the same css class name like (column) but the fourth record will use a difference class name like(column-last). Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: No code for us to see?

Comment: This is a _horrible_ question title. Please read http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Well, I've changed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS3's [`nth-child`](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/zebra-striping-tables-with-css3/) selector to selectively do so. For eg. let's say you are applying class `myClass` to the records. Now, add the following to CSS:

```
.myClass:nth-child(4n) {
    // Your new properties
}
```

Comment: This is one possible way to do it, unless you need to support versions of Internet Explorer before 9.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use css 3 you can use a modulus 3 condition when you loop through your rows

```
$classname="row1and2";
for ($rowcount=0;$rowcount < $maxrow;$rowcount++){
$classname=($rowcount%3==0)?"row3":"row1and2";
<?php echo "<tr class=$classname><td>values...</td></tr>?>
}
```

obviously this is just simple example.